# Keep beautified indentation structure when putting html into a variable?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, var, mustache

Beginning at coding, JS, today I inject an HTML template several times into the HTML thanks to JS. However, I'am confused by the systematic need to minify the html indentation and fold all the dozen(s) of lines --div, h1, span, table, tr, td, tt-- into a single var line. Minified html is both harder to ready and frequently need to be beautified back along the testing phase.

Also: **is there a way to keep Beautified indented html in variable ?**

Some syntaxe to have a valid version of:

```
var exampleTpl = "
      <div data-demo-html="true">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h4>Heading</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-inset="true">
              <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
"
```

Best thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For templating purpose, you should have a look at the example on [Handlebars.js homepage](http://handlebarsjs.com#getting-started) :

#### Declare your template

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

#### Compile a template in JavaScript

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

#### Inflate the HTML

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
var html    = template(context);
```

This will result in an instance of your template (value injected into your template) :

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My New Post</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You COULD do it like this:

```
var exampleTpl =
      '<div data-demo-html="true">' + 
        '<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">' +
          '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">' +
            '<h4>Heading</h4>' +
            '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-inset="true">' +
              '<li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>' +
              '<li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>' +
              '<li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>' +
            '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>';
```

If you really wanted...

However, if you're representing a template in mustache JS (just looking at your tags there), I personally add the templates into a script element, and then access them using innerHTML as is suggested by some templating libraries (such as handlebarsjs.com).

eg:

```
    <script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
     <div data-demo-html="true">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h4>Heading</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-inset="true">
              <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a syntax which is just perfect, without needing the '+', would be cool. Thanks for your trick too

Comment: @Hugolpz I've updated the answer. Is this something more like what you were hoping for? Are you actually using mustache JS?

Comment: I'd recommend against using `type="text/html"` with a template, the browser might try to interpret the template as HTML and make a mess of things.

Comment: @muistooshort it hasn't caused me any problems in the past, but I see that handlebars have updated their examples to use text/x-handlebars-template - so it's probably a good call. Better for semantics.